How can I compute the factorial of a complex number?
To work with complex numbers, I created a struct Cmplx that stores the real and imaginary parts in two separate variables.
struct Cmplx
{
    long double real, imag;
};

I'm having difficulty computing the factorial of a Cmplx, i.e., (a + bi)!. I could use the gamma function, but I don't know how to extend it to a struct. I tried to calculate it using powers, but it required log((a+bi)!) which leads me back to the problem of computing the factorial.

std::complex already exists.

Instead of pow three times, look up function hypot.

There's the std::tgamma function for buit-in numeric types. But no counterpart for std::complex. I guess the mathematical evaluation of the integral in complex domain is too complex.

Factorials of complex numbers are rather esoteric. If your question is "How is factorial defined for complex numbers (in terms of real and imaginary components)?" that's a question for math.stackexchange.com. If you're having difficulty converting that pre-existing formula into code, that's a slightly different question than you've posted here. There's also the big question of why you're attempting this in the first place. I've a feeling this may be an XY problem, where the thing you're really trying to address doesn't actually need the computation.

The best I got was gsl_sf_lngamma_complex_e: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html#gamma-and-beta-functions

Re "I'm having difficulty computing the factorial": Can you be more specific? E.g., what were the symptoms? Please respond by editing (changing) your question, not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** without *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

You can use Lanczos approximation for estimating gamma:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>

struct Cmplx
{
    long double real, imag;

    Cmplx(long double r = 0, long double i = 0) : real(r), imag(i) {}

    static const std::complex<long double> gamma(const std::complex<long double> &z)
    {
        static const long double g = 8.0;
        static const long double p[] = {
            0.9999999999999999298L,
            1975.3739023578852322L,
            -4397.3823927922428918L,
            3462.6328459862717019L,
            -1156.9851431631167820L,
            154.53815050252775060L,
            -6.2536716123689161798L,
            0.034642762454736807441L,
            -7.4776171974442977377e-7L,
            6.3041253821852264261e-8L,
            -2.7405717035683877489e-8L,
            4.0486948817567609101e-9L};

        std::complex<long double> x = p[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]); ++i)
            x += p[i] / (z + static_cast<long double>(i));

        std::complex<long double> t = z + g - 0.5L;
        return std::pow(2 * M_PI, 0.5L) * std::pow(t, z - 0.5L) * std::exp(-t) * x;
    }

    Cmplx factorial() const
    {
        std::complex<long double> z(real, imag);
        std::complex<long double> res = gamma(z + 1.0L);
        return Cmplx(res.real(), res.imag());
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cmplx z(1.5L, 0.5L);
    Cmplx res = z.factorial();
    std::cout << z.real << " + " << z.imag << "i\n";
    std::cout << res.real << " + " << res.imag << "i\n";
}


Prints

1.5 + 0.5i


0.579116 + 0.294109i

